# Wrong sql SUM() positive with negative digits

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have table column that have positive and negative float digits. When I do query to get SUM() of all digits, it's returns wrong result.

Table:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | user_id | points |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |      38 | 30.5   |
|  2 |      38 | -5.3   |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT SUM(points) FROM table WHERE user_id=38
```

Result:

```
25.199999809265137
```

Why is this happening? Why I don't get `25.2` as the result?

Comment: is there any value after one place of point?

Comment: could you post the table definition? If `points` is created as `DECIMAL(10,2)` everything works as expected.

Comment: @eggyal because of reason for this case. It is duplicate because of root of the problem. (I wasn't so sure about it's a dupe of that certain question - but.. suggest better alternatives)

Comment: This is what happens with floating point values.  If this matters to you, then used fixed point types such as `decimal`.

Comment: @AlmaDo: Having a similar answer **does not** make a question a duplicate.  The test is "*is, from the questioner's perspective, this problem identical to that faced in the other question?*"

Comment: @vhu: Now *that* is a duplicate!  +1

Comment: Try the following: `SELECT ROUND(SUM(points), 1) AS Sum1Dec FROM MyTable WHERE user_id = 38`

Comment: sorry for the duplicate, couldn't found same question :( used DECIMAL as a type of column and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-float.html):

> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value represented internally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your points field is a float, which is not exact.

"Approximate value" According to [the mysql dcoumentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).

Use decimal or numeric types to make exact calcuations with a known amount of numbers behind the decimal point.

Or round the result of your query on 1 digit, because your sources are also 1 digit behind the decimal point. But know that it's rounded and exact comaprison is not possible (better: not 100% exact and predictable)